# Mybatis mapper when using 2nd normal form database normalization

Tags: orm, mybatis, ibatis, database-normalization

I have a situation where I need to use mybatis where we use the second form of normalization. For example, I am mentioning two tables **Table_One** and **Table_Two**, whose PKs are in the Table **Table_Key** . Now I am trying to map these into POJOs with Classes **ClassOne** and **ClassTwo** shown below. The issue is that I will not be able to fetch the columns **rel_data** and **rel_user** here, as I do not have any fields created for these columns in either of the POJOs for the first and second classes/tables.

I understand that mybatis is not a ORM technology and acts more like a data mapping layer. If so, do I need to create another POJO for the relationship table to fetch the data in this table?

```
Table_One {
    one_key,
    one_desc
    :
    :
}

Table_Two{
    two_key,
    two_desc
    :
    :
}

Table_Key{
    one_key,
    two_key,
    rel_date,
    rel_user
}

ClassOne{
    private String oneKey;
    private String oneDesc;
    private ClassTwo classTwo;
    //getter setter
}

ClassTwo{
    private String twoKey;
    private String twoDesc;
    //getter setter
}

<resultMap type="One" id="oneResultMap">
        <id column="one_key" property="id" />
        <result column="one_desc" property="Desc" />
        <association property="two" resultMap="twoResultMap"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap type="Two" id="twoResultMap">
        <id column="two_key" property="id" />
        <result column="two_desc" property="Desc" />
</resultMap>
```

Comment: The main question here is how do you want to work with data from this table on java side? What kind of operation you need on it? What are use-cases that require this data? Before you get answers to these questions there is no sense to discuss how to map this in mybatis.